# How to install python wheel without using pip?

Tags: python, package, python-wheel

I have downloaded .whl and trying to install it. Can you tell me the possible ways of installing wheel without using `pip`.
For tar.gz files, I executed `python setup.py install` and it installed my package.

How the same can be done for wheel when there is no `setup.py` file in it?

Comment: rename it to filename.zip and extract and you can work with it. it is very bad practice though

Comment: It doesn't address the dependencies which must also be manually handled.

Comment: @metatoaster @Ivonet have extracted using 7zip and it it is returning me 2 folders with all the files contained in it. Now what needs to be done for installing the wheel. So, that when I do ```pip list``` it shows me the installed package

Answer (score 0):

**.whl**: A compressed file like **Zip Achieve.**

**How to install?**

- Install **Winrar** or other software that can extract compressed files.
- Extract your **.whl** file in a safe folder.
- Add that directory to your **Path Variables.**
- Now everything is done.

It's bad practice to install a **.whl file.** You should use **PIP.**

Well, I recommend you to extract your **.whl** file in that folder where all **Python modules** are installed.

Comment: This will not correctly install a wheel distribution. It is also the job of the installer to compile .py files into .pyc files, collect and install any dependencies of the wheel, and also to write out any console scripts entry points to bin dir. These files don't actually exist in the .whl, so if you just unzip a wheel you won't get those and the installation is incomplete.